# How do i get "sed" to delete everything else but email address. 

Tags: sed

how do i get "sed" to delete everything else but email address.

```
db dump: someusername ::: kRW...0fPc ::: $2a$10$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com
```

Comment: are these email addresses on separate lines or can they be a sentence like `this user's email is foo@example.com` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Some sample data would help a lot.

Comment: db dump:
someusername ::: kRW...0fPc ::: $2a$10$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com

Ignore (...), just protecting privacy cutting the strings

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does it have to be sed? What about grep? Here's how to use it with the regex you gave:

```
$ cat dbdump.txt 
db dump: someusername ::: kRW...0fPc ::: $2a$10$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com
another line with two e-mail addresses <test@example.com> on it -- bob@example.org

$ grep -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b' dbdump.txt
joesmith@gmail.com
test@example.com
bob@example.org
```

The `-o` flag prints only the matching portions, i.e. just the e-mail addresses. `-i` makes the matching case insensitive. It even finds multiple e-mail addresses on the same line.

**Edit:** I couldn't resist the `-EiEio`. I suppose `grep -Eio` or `egrep -io` would also work...

Comment: These days 5-character domains also can be used, replace last 4 with 5:
```
grep -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,5}\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

This requires GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/\n&\n/ig;s/(^|\n)[^@]*(\n|$)/\n/g;s/^\n|\n$//g;/^$/d' inputfile
```

- split input lines so email addresses and other strings are separated by newlines
- erase sequences that consist of only non-@ characters delimited by newlines or the beginning or end of the input line
- erase extra newlines and blank lines

Answer (score 1):

The following will work no matter where the email address is in the line but *only* if there is one email address per line.  If there are more than one it's going to only show the last one in the line.  It also won't touch lines that don't have valid email addresses in them

```
sed 's/^.* \([^@ ]\+@[^ ]\+\) \?.*$/\1/'
```

#### Input

```
$ cat dbdump
this line with no valid @ email address is untouched
::: a0$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com
::: a0$... foo@example.com db dump: someusername :::
```

#### Output

```
$  sed 's/^.* \([^@ ]\+@[^ ]\+\) \?.*$/\1/' ./dbdump
this line with no valid @ email address is untouched
joesmith@gmail.com
foo@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "db dump: someusername ::: kRW...0fPc ::: $2a$10$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com"|sed 's/.*::: //' joesmith@gmail.com
```

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "db dump: someusername ::: kRW...0fPc ::: $2a$10$...aucvkDt86 ::: joesmith@gmail.com"|awk '{print $NF}'
```

EDIT: Given the new info in your comment - it's quite hard to do what you ask without any regularity. Check the Syntax section here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Standard says that e.g. `1$%3{C}@example.com` is a valid email address (believe it or not). You can even quote it (the example given in the article is `John Doe@example.com`). So, by following the standard it's almost impossible to recognize the valid e-mail.

If you restrict your search, you can e.g. extract the lines containing `@` by first doing:

```
cat your-file.txt|grep @
```

then do some of the above. You can even do something like this:

```
$ echo "garbage John.Doe123@example.com garbage"|sed 's/[^@]* \([a-zA-Z0-9.]*@[^ ]*\).*/\1/'
John.Doe123@example.com
```

Note that the above works under the following assumptions:

- There's a space before an email address
- There are no spaces in an email address itself
- There is one email address in the line (it will actually get only the first one, so it can work with more then one)
- The `local-part` (all before `@`) contains only letters (lower- or upper-case), digits and a dot

Expand the character set (`[a-zA-Z0-9.]`) as you wish to make it less restrictive - e.g. you can do `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]` to include `-` and `_`.

Comment: Not working out, only for the lines with emails. __sorry__ my fault, should have added that not all lines have emails or all the elements between ":::"

Comment: Any way of getting this Regex '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b' to work with sed? Where sed deletes everything else but that and add a "/r" return after each?

Comment: See the edit. As for the regex you gave, you should be able to use something like: `\b\([A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\)\b` to get the first group (`s/.../\1/` - `\1` is the first group). You need to escape `\+`.

Comment: All your __assumptions__ are correct, and i'm still not getting a clean result.